# condensing a bash script to have less line of code

Tags: bash

I'm Trying to condense my bash script I was hoping that you guys could help me. It's a Script that fakes the hacking of a website.

```
# **Heres The Code** #

#!/usr/bin/bash
clear
echo -e "\e[32mWhat Website Do You Want to Hack\e[0m"
read website
if [[ $website = *".com"* ]] && [[ $website = *"www."* ]];
then

        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo Now Initializing Packages
        sleep 1s
        clear
        sleep .5s
        echo Initializing Packages [#---------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [##--------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [###-------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [####------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [#####-----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [######----]
            sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [#######---]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [########--]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [#########-]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Initializing Packages [##########]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Now Receiving Packages
        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [#---------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [##--------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [###-------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [####------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [#####-----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [######----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [#######---]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [########--]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [#########-]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Receiving Packages [##########]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Now Cracking Packages
        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [#---------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [##--------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [###-------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [####------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [#####-----]
            sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [######----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [#######---]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [########--]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [#########-]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Cracking Packages [##########]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo -e "\e[31mERROR FIREWALL\e[0m"
        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo Attempt 2
        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo -e "\e[34mNow Hacking $website\e[0m"
        sleep 1s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [#---------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [##--------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [###-------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [####------]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [#####-----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [######----]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [#######---]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [########--]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [#########-]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        echo Hacking $website [##########]
        sleep .5s
        clear
        ping -c 6 $website
        sleep 1s
        clear
        sleep 1s
        echo -e "\e[32mConnected To $website\e[0m"
        sleep 1s
else
    echo -e "\e[31mERROR INVAILD URL\e[0m"
fi
```

Comment: How about using loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use loops for all the repeated bits of code.

```
hashes='##########'
dashes='----------'
for hashcount in {1..10}; do
    clear
    sleep .5s
    dashcount=$((10-hashcount))
    echo "Initializing Packages [${hashes:0:$hashcount}${dashes:0:$dashcount}]"
done
```